# How to convert a xls/xlsx file using Syncfusion in C#

Tags: c#, syncfusion

I am getting the System out of memory exception. The size of my xls file is 357 mb. I am not sure what has to be configured to allow opening of heavy files.

I'm refering to the documentation available on this website https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/xlsio/excel-to-pdf-conversion

The stacktrace is as below:

> at Syncfusion.XlsIO.Parser.Biff_Records.BiffContinueRecordRaw.ExtractContinueRecords()
>      at Syncfusion.XlsIO.Parser.Biff_Records.MSODrawingGroupRecord.ParseStructure()
>      at Syncfusion.XlsIO.Parser.Biff_Records.BiffRecordRawWithArray.ParseStructure(DataProvider provider, Int32 iOffset, Int32 iLength, ExcelVersion version)
>      at Syncfusion.XlsIO.Parser.Biff_Records.BiffRecordRaw.FillRecord(BinaryReader reader, DataProvider provider, IDecryptor decryptor, Byte[] arrBuffer)

Please let me know if any information required.

Edit 2:
Code

```
ExcelEngine excelEngine = new ExcelEngine();
IApplication application = excelEngine.Excel;
application.DefaultVersion = ExcelVersion.Excel2013;
**IWorkbook workbook = application.Workbooks.Open(src_file, ExcelOpenType.Automatic);**
ExcelToPdfConverter converter = new ExcelToPdfConverter(workbook);
```

The line at which the exception occurs has been marked with asteriks

Comment: Can you show us your code? And indicate the line in which the exception occurred?

Comment: @ChristianMurschall, I have updated my question with the code.